# What would allow a human being to create a rift in space-time and access parallel universes?

Tags: alternate-worlds, alternate-earth, dimensions

I'm creating a story where there are individuals that can travel to parallel/alternate earths. Obviously this is all fantasy but hypothetically speaking, how would you ground this is in some related real-world science? Based on the theoretical information we have about parallel/branching worlds, how would you connect it to human biology and explain how someone could tunnel through into another world?

Comment: I'd recommend thiotimoline, personally, seeing as it's a unique chemical which exists the past, present, and future, but asking an open-ended question like this is a little too opinion based, in my opinion.

Comment: Trillions of tons of negative mass.

Comment: As all of the possible answers are beyond actual science and entirely opinion based on how you want to hand wave the situation, this is gonna get closed for opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

**Astral projection.**

[image: astral projections]
http://spiritofmaat.com/magazine/april-2015-the-abundant-earth/astral-travel-for-beginners-what-to-expect-and-5-tips/

Dumb matter is confined to its own dimension.  Enlightened spirit energy is not so confined.  Through astral projection a being in this dimension can project consciousness to visit other parallel dimensions as well as more esoteric planes.

This is also safer than actually visiting these places in the flesh as it is easier to find your way back home.  The visiting astral traveler might experience other realms as a disembodied ghostlike spirit, or might manifest as some physical presence, or possibly take possession of a physical presence that already inhabits that realm.

There is also the possibility that the astral traveler fell asleep and had a groovy dream, or is on drugs.  Or maybe all of these things happened!

Comment: This way of traveling takes a lot of energy, they would wake up with a serious case of the munchies!

Comment: Delusional schizophrenics may be master astral travellers.